# CSS blurs - am I offsetting to GPU correctly?

Tags: css

So, as we all know, `filter:blur(5px)` in CSS can be real slow without little browser hacks such as `transform: translateZ(0px)` to force it to be rendered by GPU.

Now, I've got a 1000px by 500px JPG I'd like to blur on hover, but this is extremely slow. I've got `translateZ(0px)`, `perspective: 1000` on it, but it doesn't seem to make much of a difference.

Is that the best I can hope for? Any ideas on how I could speed this up?

Comment: filters should be GPU accelerated natively by most browsers by now. Are you sure you've got Allow Hardware Acceleration preference switched on?

Comment: Very much so - all transforms, opacity changes etc are smooth as silk. I'm starting to think that perhaps a blur of that size might just be too much for it? With 16GB RAM and 8 cores it is a bit of a surprise, though.

Comment: use `transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;` it's working smoothly .

Answer (score 0):

There is a really simple solution to this. Don't animate the blur value. Rather, animate opacity between two images; one blurred and one not blurred. This way you will only need to render the blur effect once, but you get basically the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar problem when i tried to play animation on a background blur overlay.

```html
<div class="overlay backdrop-blur-2xl bg-slate-200/20">
  <div class="animate-box animate-pulse"></div>
<div>
```

This animatian eat all of my gpu.
so  i tried the answer above said.I use a image  as the overlay's background image.And the image must be .jpg format,the png format will still take a lot gpu resource.